# remove some text after - from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove some text from string or integer using javascipt or jquery..

I have string `"flow-[s/c]"`, `"flow-max[s/c]"`,`"flow-min[s/c]"`, `"Usage-[s/c]"`, `"temperature"`

And I want for each :
`"flow"`, `"flow-max"`,`"flow-min"`, `"Usage"`, `"temperature"`

As you can see. I want to remove all the data after `-` found expect `flow-max` and `flow-min`

What I am doing :

```
var legendName = $(textElement).text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
```

Taking the legend Name example :  `"flow-[s/c]", "flow-max[s/c]"`

```
var displayVal = legendName.split('-')[0];
```

remove all the data after `-` found

But I am not able to add condition for `flow-max` because at this case I will be having two `-` and two place like `flow-min-[s/c]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var displayVal = $(textElement).text().replace(/\-?\[s\/c\]/, "");
```

The code `/\-?\[s\/c\]/` is a regular expression, where:

- `/` at the start and end are the delimiters of the expression.
- `\` is an escape character, indicating that the following character should be taken literally (in our example we need it in front of `-`, `[`, `/` and `]` because those are control character for regular expressions).
- `?` means the previous character is optional.

So it replaces an optional dash (`-`) followed by the text `[s/c]`, with an empty string.

Comment: Or even shorter, but this might cause false positives:
`legendName.replace(/\-?\[.+/, "");`

Comment: Could you please describe what the problem is, @JavascriptCoder? What results are you getting? What is your code?

Comment: I edited my code slightly, maybe it works better for you now?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this simple regex `/(max|min)\[.*?]|-\[.*?]/g`. The regex is simple, if you see what it does separately.

The logic has been separated by `|` operator.

```
legendName = legendName.replace(/(max|min)\[.*?]|-\[.*?]/, "$1");
```

Comment: No: `"flow-max[s/c]".replace(/-\[.*?]/g,"");` returns `"flow-max[s/c]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastoccur = legendName.lastIndexOf("-");` to find the last occur of "-" and then split your string.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

Comment: This won't work on `flow-max[s/c]`, where the result needs to be `flow-max`, not `flow`.